# How to pass values directly to std::span?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have a function that receives a span.

```
void p(std::span<int> s) {
    for(auto x : s) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
```

How can I pass values directly into the function? For instance.

```
p({1,2,3})
```

Any workaround?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can construct an `std::array`:

```
p(std::array{1,2,3});
```

This also requires you to use `std::span<const int>` instead of `std::span<int>`, since the latter expects a **modifiable** range (which doesn't seem to be your intent), and rejects rvalues.

---

`p({{1,2,3}});` also works.

Answer (score 3):

the closest to passing `{1, 2, 3}` would be to pass an [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

```
auto list = { 1, 2, 3 };
p(list);
```

or inlined:

```
p( std::initializer_list{ 1, 2, 3 } );
```

---

But however you take the span, `p` needs to accept an `std::span<const int>` to work, like HolyBlackCat mentioned..

Comment: This is strange that clang fails on your version: https://godbolt.org/z/cxTxMneeo

Comment: @MarekR That's because template deduction guide of `std::initializer_list` isn't regulated in the standard, so clang doesn't do it. Just change the parameter to `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten what you need to write before `{}` by providing your own adapter. For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <span>

void p(std::span<const int> s) {
    for(auto x : s) {
        std::cout << x << ' ';
    }
}

template<typename T>
class spn
{
public:
    spn(std::initializer_list<T> list) : span_(list) {}
    operator std::span<const T>() {
        return span_;
    }
private:
    std::span<const T> span_;
};

int main()
{
    p(spn{1,2,3});
    return 0;
}
```